# django - initialize model fields including manytomanyfields

Tags: django, django-models, model, many-to-many, django-orm

All,

I have a set related models:

```
 class Foo(models.Model):
   fooName = models.CharField()
   bars = models.ManyToManyField("Bar")

 class Bar(models.Model):
   barName = models.CharField()
```

When I create a new one, I would like for it to have a default set of data.  This is pretty easy to do for normal fields.  But I'm not sure what to do for relationship fields.  Let's pretend that I want every foo to be initialized with the name "I am a foo" and a set of three bars, each with specific names (say, "I am bar one," "I am bar two," and "I am bar three.").

```
 def Initialize(self)
   self.fooName = "I am a foo"
   self.bars = ?!?
```

I'm just not sure how to go about this.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

You may not use a many to many relation on a model instance that doesn't have a primary key.

1. **Save the model**, to enable m2m relations
2. **Save your other model**, to enable m2m relations on the other side as well
3. **Use .add()**, for example yourmodel.bars.add(othermodel)

If you want to set default, initial data, you should [use fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/#providing-initial-data-with-fixtures).

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using django's [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/). Every time an instance of your `Foo` model is created, also create the other information you require:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    ...

from django.db.models.signals import post_save 
from signals import create_initial_data
post_save.connect(create_initial_data, sender=Foo)
```

and in a file called `signals.py`:

```
from models import Bar
def create_initial_data(sender, instance, created, raw):
    if created and sender == 'Foo':
        bar_1 = Bar(...)
        bar_2 = Bar(...)
        ...
        bar_1.save()
        bar_2.save()
        ...
        instance.bars.add(bar_1, bar_2, ...)
        instance.save()
```